Artifacts of the AVAssetWriter() record result
I'm trying to develop a video camera with "live" effects. The process is based on AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate(), MTKView() and a computing pipeline. As long as the application is running and recording, no problems arise. The problems start when I play the finished video. Unpleasant artifacts appear on it, which it is unclear how to remove.
This is what the captureOutput function looks like:
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
        guard CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        let timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
        
        if connection == hardware.videoOut.connection(with: .video) {
            self.sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer
            self.hardware.preview.draw()
            
            if self.focusImageVisibleSeconds > 0 {
                if let buffer = sampleBuffer.imageBuffer {
                    var ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: buffer)
                    
                    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: ciImage.extent.size.width/2, y: ciImage.extent.size.height/2)
                    let point = CGPoint(x: center.x - 100, y: center.y - 100)
                    let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
                    
                    ciImage = ciImage.cropped(to: CGRect(origin: point, size: size))
                    
                    let image = self.hardware.context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.focusImage = image }
                }
                
                
                self.focusImageVisibleSeconds -= self.activeDevice?.activeVideoMinFrameDuration.seconds ?? 0
                
                
            } else if self.focusImage != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { self.focusImage = nil }
            }
        }
        
        guard canWrite() else { return }
        
        if let sessionAtSourceTime = sessionAtSourceTime {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self else { return }
                let duration = Int(timestamp.seconds - sessionAtSourceTime.seconds)
                if self.duration < duration { self.duration = duration }
            }
        } else {
            assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: timestamp)
            sessionAtSourceTime = timestamp
        }
        
        if connection == hardware.audioOut.connection(with: .audio) && self.aInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
            self.hardware.writeQueue.async {
                self.aInput?.append(sampleBuffer)
            }
        }
   }

This is how the draw() MetalView() function looks like:
func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        
        guard let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer, let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        let stamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)

        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
        
        var luminanceCVTexture: CVMetalTexture?
        CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, hardware.textureCache!, imageBuffer, nil, .r8Unorm, width, height, 0, &luminanceCVTexture)

        var crominanceCVTexture: CVMetalTexture?
        CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, hardware.textureCache!, imageBuffer, nil, .rg8Unorm, width/2, height/2, 1, &crominanceCVTexture)

        guard let luminanceCVTexture = luminanceCVTexture,
              let inputLuminance = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(luminanceCVTexture),
              let crominanceCVTexture = crominanceCVTexture,
              let inputCrominance = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(crominanceCVTexture)
        else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.hardware.preview.drawableSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
        
        guard let drawable: CAMetalDrawable = self.hardware.preview.currentDrawable else  { return }
        guard let commandBuffer = hardware.commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(), let computeCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else { return }

        computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(hardware.computePipelineState)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(inputLuminance, index: 0)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(inputCrominance, index: 1)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, index: 2)
        
        if let cubeBuffer = self.cubeBuffer {
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(cubeBuffer.0, offset: 0, index: 0)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(cubeBuffer.1, offset: 0, index: 1)
        } else {
            let lutSizeBuffer = self.hardware.device.makeBuffer(bytes: [2], length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(lutSizeBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
            let lutBuffer = self.hardware.device.makeBuffer(bytes: neutralLutArray, length: neutralLutArray.count * MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.stride, options: [])
            computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(lutBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
        }
        
        computeCommandEncoder.setBytes([Float(self.showNoise ? 1.0 : 0.0)], length: 1 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size, index: 2)
        computeCommandEncoder.setBytes([Float(stamp.seconds)], length: 1 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size, index: 3)
        
        computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(inputLuminance.threadGroups(), threadsPerThreadgroup: inputLuminance.threadGroupCount())
        computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { buffer in
            
            self.hardware.writeQueue.async {
                 
                guard let adaptor = self.adaptor else { return }
                guard self.isWriting && self.assetWriter?.status == .writing && self.sessionAtSourceTime != nil && self.vInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true
                else { return }
                
                var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
                let pixelBufferStatus = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, adaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)
                
                guard let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, pixelBufferStatus == kCVReturnSuccess else { return }
                
                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                
                let lumaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)
                let chromaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)
                
                guard let liminanceBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0),
                      let chrominanceBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1)
                else { return }
                
                inputLuminance.getBytes(liminanceBytes, bytesPerRow: lumaBytesPerRow, from: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, inputLuminance.width, inputLuminance.height), mipmapLevel: 0)
                inputCrominance.getBytes(chrominanceBytes, bytesPerRow: chromaBytesPerRow, from: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, inputCrominance.width, inputCrominance.height), mipmapLevel: 0)
 
                if (!adaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: stamp)) { print("Problem appending pixel buffer at time: \(stamp)") }
                
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
            }
        }
        
        commandBuffer.commit()
        
    }

Here is the process of setting up AVAssetWriter:
func setupWriter(for range: VideoDynamicRange, with format: VideoFormat) {
        
        guard let activeDevice = self.activeDevice else { return }

        var format = format
        
        guard let width = hardware.videoOut.videoSettings["Width"] as? Int else { return }
        guard let height = hardware.videoOut.videoSettings["Height"] as? Int else { return }
        let frameRate = Int(1/activeDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration.seconds)
        
        if height > 2100 && frameRate > 30 { format = .hevc }
        
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("\(UUID().uuidString).\(format == .mp4 ? "MP4" : "MOV")")
        
        guard var vSettings = self.hardware.videoOut.recommendedVideoSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: format == .mp4 ? .mp4 : .mov) else { return }
    
        var compressionSettings: [String: Any] = vSettings["AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey"] as! [String: Any]
        compressionSettings["ExpectedFrameRate"] = frameRate
        
        compressionSettings["AverageBitRate"] = Int(0.125/activeDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration.seconds)*width*height
        
        switch range {
        case .sdr:
            compressionSettings["ProfileLevel"] = kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel
            vSettings[AVVideoColorPropertiesKey] = [AVVideoColorPrimariesKey: AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2,
                                                  AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2,
                                                       AVVideoYCbCrMatrixKey: AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2]
        case .hdr10:
            compressionSettings["ProfileLevel"] = kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main10_AutoLevel
            vSettings[AVVideoColorPropertiesKey] = [AVVideoColorPrimariesKey: AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_2020,
                                                  AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_SMPTE_ST_2084_PQ,
                                                       AVVideoYCbCrMatrixKey: AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_2020]
        case .dolbyVision:
            compressionSettings["ProfileLevel"] = kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main10_AutoLevel
            vSettings[AVVideoColorPropertiesKey] = [AVVideoColorPrimariesKey: AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_2020,
                                                  AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_2100_HLG,
                                                       AVVideoYCbCrMatrixKey: AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_2020]
        }
        
        vSettings["AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey"] = compressionSettings
        
        
        do {
            
            self.assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(url: url, fileType: format == .mp4 ?  AVFileType.mp4 : AVFileType.mov)
            self.assetWriter?.metadata = self.makeAVMetaData(with: location)
            
            print(self.assetWriter as Any)
            //Add video input
            self.vInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: vSettings)
            self.vInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
            self.vInput?.mediaTimeScale = CMTimeScale(600)
            
            switch self.orientation {
            case .portraitUpsideDown: vInput?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
            case .landscapeRight: vInput?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi*3/2)
            case .landscapeLeft: vInput?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
            default: vInput?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
            }
            
            guard vInput != nil else { return }
            
            let sourcePixelBufferAttributes:[String:AnyObject] = [
                kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String:NSNumber(value: Int32(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)),
                kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String:NSNumber(value: width),
                kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String:NSNumber(value: height)
            ]
            
            adaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: vInput!, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributes)
            if self.assetWriter?.canAdd(vInput!) == true { assetWriter?.add(vInput!) }
            
            //Add audio input
            if let aSettings = self.hardware.audioOut.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: format == .mp4 ? .mp4 : .mov) {
                
                self.aInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: aSettings)
                self.aInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
                
                guard aInput != nil else { return }
                if self.assetWriter?.canAdd(aInput!) == true { assetWriter?.add(aInput!) }
            }
            
            self.assetWriter?.startWriting()
            
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

Link to the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/VKostin8311/LiveEffectCamera
I will be very grateful for any help
PS: I use biplane textures and metal to save device resources. When using BGRA CMSampleBuffer or Core Image, the device heats up quickly.
